# Array.prototype.values() is undefined - using Babel to transpile ES6 in NodeJS environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

My setup is:

```
$ babel --version
6.3.15 (babel-core 6.3.15)
$ node --version
v5.1.0
```

Using Webstorm 11 IDE in case that is important too.

I am using Babel(js) to transpile the following ES6, and have set up some logging to verify:

```
Array.from([ 'a', 'b' ].keys());
Array.from([ 'a', 'b' ].values());  // TypeError: ["a","b"].values is not a function
Array.from([ 'a', 'b' ].entries());
```

Can verify this v.quickly:

```
Array.prototype.values === undefined) // true
```

Note that **keys**, and **entries** both exist.

Any ideas what the likely cause is? (Have I missed a special options flag or something on Babel to switch on support of this feature?). Thanks for any help, and shall continue to check documentation etc in meantime.

Comment: You have to manually require the polyfill https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Comment: Thanks Paolo, taking a look now. you may wish to put your comment into a one line answer so i can credit you if it works.

Comment: Just in case of another missing feature, you should take a look at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6 ;)

Comment: Excellent, thank you, this is the solution. Mocha tests all passing now - mystery solved. Cheers!

Comment: @juliobetta - thanks, I had that link open, but didn't fully understand the meaning of "Babel + Core JS". Great suggestion all the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing an answer for completeness. BabelJS requires an extra polyfill package to extend it with some extra ES6+ features - such as the one in this question.

```
npm install babel-polyfill --save
```

Then insert the following require statement towards the top of the affected module to obtain required (generator) behaviour:

```
require("babel-polyfill");
```

This should be all you need, just importing the module adds required polyfill

Answer (score 3):

I know, you accepted the answer, but I'd highly recommend to use [**core-js** standard library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) for node.js.

With this library you'll forget seeing any problems on JS features support.
It includes polyfills for ECMAScript 5, ECMAScript 6: promises, symbols, collections, iterators, typed arrays, ECMAScript 7+ proposals, setImmediate, etc. Some additional features such as dictionaries or extended partial application.

It's easy to install dependency and to use it:

```
npm i core-js --save
```

Then within your project, use it this way, to include all the features it support:

```
// Without global namespace pollution 
var core = require('core-js/library');
```

Or like this, if you want to include only specific features (in your case you was missing *Array.prototype.values()*):

```
require('core-js/fn/array/values');
```

This lib is a "must-have" to me for every project, after I discovered it for myself. Package description can be found at official page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js

Comment: thanks for this answer. I have upvoted it on basis it looks like a good option. I realise that babel leans on this library internally, so for now I shall leave the accepted answer as-is. If more voters choose this answer then I'd be happy to assign this as a correct answer.

Comment: As arcseldon already said, babel-polyfill uses core-js itself and it loads all the additional runtimes needed (such as regenerator).